# Docker for Windows - access container in local network

Tags: windows, docker, networking, nexus3

I have installed Docker for Windows on which I have running Nexus Repository Manager container. Now I want to make my nexus container be accessible from other pc's located in internal network.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to map the port to the container.
Example for port 443:

> docker run -d -p 443:443 $imagename$

You also have to make sure that your windows firewall is not blocking that port. Maybe you have to create a new rule.

BR
Hannes

Comment: Ok. So then only thing I will have to do is to check my IP and share it with someone who wants to perform operations on nexus container? :)

Comment: I think yes. When the computers can reach each other. Just test it.