# How can I run my Docker Image and see working app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, jib

I created a sample web-app in Java (with using Gradle and SpringBoot) and then dockerized it with Jib. In my build.gradle file there is a row : "ports = ['9090']" because I want to see web-app on this port. And in my application.properties file there is a row : "server.port=9090".

Docker Image succesfully created. But when I run this image I couldn't see results of its working.
  If I run jar file everything is OK. Web-app works on 9090 port.

I want to see my web-app working, when I execute command **docker run** .
  How can I change the port of the image or of anything else ( NettyWebServer properties ) to see the running image on that port what I want ?
  Can you help me with this issue please ?
  Thank You.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003431/docker-for-windows-access-container-in-local-network/52003606#52003606

Maybe you have to pass the port to the container.

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: did you run like this `docker run -p 9090:9090` ? that mean map port `9090` inside container to `9090` on host machine

Comment: 1. My operation system is Win 10.

Comment: 2. I tried do like this :
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 47ab55bdf5b7
It didn't help me.
C:\Users\gazinaa>docker run -d -p 9090:9090 47ab55bdf5b7
2dac0a50d8a528e5895075f22498604af9bcf58fd212d3a11286aa59c824803a
But image doesn't start on this port.

Comment: 3. When I put the command docker run among the messages I see : 
2019-01-22 06:57:19.719  INFO [-,,,] 1 --- [-server-epoll-5] r.ipc.netty.tcp.BlockingNettyContext     : Started HttpServer on /0.0.0.0:8080
2019-01-22 06:57:19.719  INFO [-,,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
Maybe I must change the port of this NettyWebServer ? How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a different port in your docker image than on your local environment u can copy different `application.properties` file with `server.port=XXXX` specified using this command in your `Dockerfile`

```
COPY ./src/main/resources/docker-application.properties /opt/my-app/docker-application.properties
```

Then in your `entrypoint.sh`

```
java -jar /opt/my-app/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=/opt/my-app/docker-application.properties
```

After building the app with your tool (be maven or gradle) you need to run following commands (assuming you are in the app directory with your `Dockerfile` etc)

```
docker build -t my-app .
docker run -d -p [desired_port]:[docker_application_properties_port] --name my-app my-app
```

The `desired_port` is the port you will put in the URL. The `docker_application_properties_port` is the one you specified in your `docker-application.properties` file.

If you are running `Windows OS` then a lot of users make a mistake trying to use `127.0.0.1:9090`. You should try using `192.168.99.100:9090` and if it doesn't work then you need to run `CMD` and then `ipconfig /all` and look for something like `Ethernet Adapter (DockerNAT)` and see the `IP` there.

Comment: Thnk you very much for help

Comment: No problem :) I assume it solved your problem?

Comment: Yes it is ! ) Now I see running docker image on proper port )

Comment: Great! You can see the logs by executing `docker logs -f my-app` or SSH into it by using `docker exec -it my-app sh`

Comment: Pijotrek, I get FileNotFoundException, when put into DockerFile this : COPY .src/main/resources/docker-application.properties /opt/my-app/docker-application.properties

Comment: is your docker container built successfully?